# How to make actions known when using ngrx-effects oftype operator

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

My code base is heavily using ngrx-effects and we use `ofType` like this:

```
  @Effect()
  someEffect$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<LoginAction>(UserActions.LOGIN)
  . . .
```

I recall reading some time back--but cannot find the reference--that ngrx effects no longer needs both the generic type instantiator and the action argument. Checking the docs, I find this example on the [v7 Update Guide](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v7#oftype-removal):

```
  @Effect()
  someEffect$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserActions.LOGIN)
  . . .
```

That is, it is using the **non**-generic flavor of `ofType`.

Now on the [ofType docs page](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/ofType) itself, it seems to affirm my recollection that both are not needed, stating:

> For backwards compatibility, when one passes a single type argument
>   `ofType<T>('something')` the result is an `Observable<T>`. Note, that T
>   completely overrides any possible inference from 'something'.
>   Unfortunately, for unknown 'actions: Actions' these types will produce
>   'Observable'. In such cases one has to manually set the generic type
>   like actions.ofType('add').

Now here's my actual bit of code:

```
    @Effect()
    toggleTokenFailure$ = this.actions$.pipe(  
      ofType<ToggleTokenActiveFailure>(ApiTokenActionTypes.TOGGLE_FAILURE),
      map(({ payload: { error } }) => new CreateNotification({
      . . .
```

If I change the `ofType` line to this:

```
    ofType(ApiTokenActionTypes.TOGGLE_FAILURE),
```

the code still works, but I lose my typing on `payload` (it becomes `any`). With the original line, the type of `payload` was `HttpErrorResponse` (because that is the type of `ToggleTokenActiveFailure.payload`).

So, per the docs I quoted above, why is my action "unknown", or more to the point, how do I make it known?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make those types known you have to either provide use `ofType<YourAction>(...)`, just like you did before or provide it to `Actions` in your constructor. In this case, it could look like that:

```
type SomeActionsType = ToggleTokenActiveFailure | OtherAction;

@Injectable()
export class SomeEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions<SomeActionsType>) {}

  . . .

  @Effect()
  toggleTokenFailure$ = this.actions$.pipe(  
    ofType(ApiTokenActionTypes.TOGGLE_FAILURE),
    map(({ payload: { error } }) => new CreateNotification({
    . . .
}
```